# How components of a web page are downloaded in responsive web design?

Tags: css, browser, web, responsive-design, media-queries

I have just started to work on responsive web design. Do media queries handle downloading components or where the process is handled ? The reason for this question is When we using different sized images in our web pages , say for example 1x image is been downloaded for smartphones , 2x images are downloaded for tablets , 4x images are downloaded for desktop browsers . Will all the sized images will get downloaded for all the browsers or How this is handled in responsive web design ? How it is applicable to all web components ?

Comment: Media queries simply define where certain CSS rules are applied, nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will describe the strategy for every kind of assets.

**Images**

The whole idea of conditional loading is not to load images with a size bigger than needed.

The [articles](http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-images-in-practice), that you can find on that matter make perfect sense, but still they are a bit tricky to implement, since the final solution will rely mostly on the back-end.

The most used technique is fairly simple: you use JavaScript methods for screen width/device detection and load a corresponding image size.

**CSS**

For conditional loading you can use media attribute of `<link>` tag. The attribute is used for specifying a `@media` query, which will control the loading.

Here is an article about [Conditional loading of resources with media queries](http://christianheilmann.com/2012/12/19/conditional-loading-of-resources-with-mediaqueries/) , which explains the usage of the attribute in details. It's quite old, but the rules are the same even today.

**JavaScript**

The control of JavaScript assets is entirely up to you. I'm not going to talk about module loaders.

[Window.matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) is the media-query based condition checker, that can be used for asset loading, if you're satisfied with [browser-support](http://caniuse.com/#search=matchMedia).

Outdated, but quite more user friendly [window.outerWidth](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_outerheight.asp)

Browser detection is described in the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery).

Comment: Thanks A Lot  .. that really helped me !!!